# Alternating (Transposition) Split Cipher

Tags: python, encryption

I am working to pass a Codewars test and cannot manage to figure out the problem. I am working to create an alternating split (transposition) cipher. I need to get the message to pull every second character and place it at the end of the string. For instance:

`"This is a test!"` should be `"hsi  etTi sats!"`

The program needs to complete the task `n` times.

Here is my code:

```
def encrypt(text, n):
    count = 0

    while count != n:
        text = text[1::2] + text[::2]
        count += 1

    return text
```

I thought the code would work, but it keeps timing out.

Comment: How do you call it? Please [edit] your question to show the full script.

Comment: The function is called through Codewars to confirm the script works. Here is an example:

Test.assert_equals(encrypt("This is a test!", 0), "This is a test!")

Comment: It [works](http://ideone.com/cntvD1) for me. This has something to do with how you run your tests. Can you be more specific?